# Sum by cases using just Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a model called Purchases that has a many-to-many relationship with Product model. I created a model to manage the table in the many-to-many relationship called PurchasedProduct. This model is related to an other model called Currency.

**Purchases table**: Id, number, created_at, updated_at.
**Product_table**: Id, description, created_at, updated_at.
**Currency table**: Id, code, name, ratio.
**Product_Purchase table**: Id, purchase_id, product_id, currency_id, quantity, price.

An `User` can purchase several `Products` then, he can pay in many `Currencies`. To manage every transaction, I want to sum the total (quantity * price) by currency. 
I've tried to do it with an accessor but all I can do is sum the product of quantity * price without consider the currency.

```
public function getTotalAttribute($value)
{
    $transformers = $this->transformers();
    return $transformers->sum(\DB::raw('quantity * price'));
}`
```

Comment: You should start here by writing the exact raw MySQL query which generates the output you want.  Then, worry about transforming that to Eloquent/PHP code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure, I have it but I'm using just laravel to looking for the results

Comment: Then you should include that query.  I think it would help you get an answer here faster.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupBy`

```
public function getTotalAttribute($value)
{
    $transformers = $this->transformers();
    return $transformers->groupBy('currency_id')
    ->selectRaw('sum(quantity * price) as sum, currency_id')
    ->get();
}
```